# How to determine the length of a string being rendered on a web page? (without using strlen())

Tags: php, html

How I can display the data in tr depending on the number of characters.

my code is:

```
<?php
$query = "select text from mytable where id=".$_POST["id"];

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);    
?>

<table>
<tr class="text-center border">
     <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr class="text-center border">
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="text-center border">
     <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if the text exceeds I want to show in the other row tr.

Comment: If the text exceeds what? What's wrong with using strlen()?

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB It's like a perfect example for what SQL Injection looks like :)

Comment: Yes...but it is just one example.

Comment: Please improve your phrasing. Consider using css text-ellipsis if you only want to support newer browsers anyways. As for your simple task an `if (strlen($row[0]) > $maxChars){ echo 'long.....' } else{ echo 'short....'}` will suffice

Comment: @Ivan, my new answer gets several strings from an array, splits each string into pieces, and display the pices, then it takes another string and repeats the process. It will work with the rows of your database, my "foreach" will walk your rows, and the inner "for i" will display the splitted row in pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `strlen`, you can use `str_split`, example:

```
<table>

<?php
$s = "This is a string that I have to display in pieces of the same size in a table.";
$arr = str_split( $s,10 ); // CONVERT STRING IN ARRAY OF PIECES OF 10 CHARS.

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $arr ); $i++ )
  echo "<tr>" .
       "  <td>" .
            $arr[ $i ] .  // DISPLAY ONE PIECE PER ROW.
       "  </td>" .
       "</tr>";
?>

</table>
```

You will get this :

[image]

Example with an array that we will pretend is a database, to test it copy-paste it in a PHP file and open it in your browser :

```
<table border="1">

<?php
$messages = Array( "Hello, dear, I would love to go to the movies tonight, give me a call!",
                   "Sorry, darling, I have an important meeting and I don't want to get fired.",
                   "Don't you love me? Is your job more important than me? You know what? Good bye forever.",
                 );

foreach ( $messages as $msg ) // WALK EACH MESSAGE.
{ $arr = str_split( $msg,10 ); // CONVERT MESSAGE IN ARRAY OF PIECES OF 10 CHARS.
  for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $arr ); $i++ ) // WALK EACH PIECE.
    echo "<tr>" .
         "  <td>" . $arr[ $i ] . "</td>" . // DISPLAY PIECE.
         "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: I've already tried that way, but I work with a text and if change does not work anymore.

Comment: What is the exact output you want, and what is the exact output you get instead?

Comment: @Ivan, I edited the answer and added another code that would work with a database (I use an array instead of a database, you will replace the array by your mysqli_query statement).

Answer (score 0):

BY default, the table cells resize to fit all data.  You don't need to do this yourself.